# HTML iframe height not working correctly in Firefox (parent container height is 100%, as well as html and body)

Tags: html, css, firefox, iframe, safari

I am trying to create an iframe with a height of 100% and a width of 100%.  The html and body are both set to 100% height, and the table that the iframe is in is also set to 100% height.  This works perfectly when using Chrome and Safari (both webkit), but does not work at all when using Firefox.  When I view the site using Firefox, the content does not fill 100% of the page height, but just a small portion.

Below is my html:

```
<?php include("checkOnLogin.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Fly Earth Staff Area</title>
<link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" height="100%" id="main" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td id="header" colspan="2"><span id="text_flyearth">Fly Earth </span><span id="text_staffarea">Staff Area</span><span id="user_info"><?php include("getUserInfo.php"); ?></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="nav"><?php include("navBarMain.html"); ?></td>
    <td id="content"><iframe height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" src="/memchat"></iframe></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

body {
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#main {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#header {
    height:40px;
    background-image:url(images/header_bg.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#text_flyearth {
    font-size:20pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    left:5px;
    color:#333;
}

#text_staffarea {
    font-size:20pt;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    left:5px;
    color:#333;
}

#nav {
    background-color:#CCC;
    width:200px;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#content {
    background-color:#FFF;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12pt;
    padding:15px;

}

.navlink:link {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navlink:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navlink:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.navlink:active {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.navlink {
    color:#333;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14pt;
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
    left:15px;
}

.navlinksmall:link {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navlinksmall:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navlinksmall:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.navlinksmall:active {
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.navlinksmall {
    color:#333;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11pt;
    position:relative;
    top:30px;
    left:15px;
}

#redlogin {
    color:#F00;
}

#user_info {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:15pt;
    text-align:right;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    top:3px;
    right:5px;
}
```

Thanks so much for any help!
Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither your table row nor table cell has a specified height, so per spec the iframe should have auto height.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  How do I fix that while still retaining a table height of 100%?  If I specify a cell or row height (other than 100%, which is what the table height is set to now), the layout will no longer adjust to the browser window's height and will be fixed.  Also, the height of the entire table is set to 100% and the first row height is set to 40px, so shouldn't the second row take up the rest of the space on the page without me having to explicitly set a row height?  That is what is allowing me to create this fluid layout based on browser window height.

Comment: Does specifying the second row height to the correct calc() expression (possibly prefixed as needed) do what you want?

Comment: Thanks again for the help!  I thought I would let you know that I set the height of each cell in the second row (nav and content) to 100%, and now everything is working as expected in Firefox and other browsers.  I now realize the 100% height of those two cells means 100% of the parent container, which, in this case, is the second row.  Thanks again!